# Definition of measurable functions whose values belong to a Banach space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal M, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $B$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.
It seems to me the most natural definition of a measurable function $f: X \rightarrow B$ is as follows.

For every $E\in \mathcal M$ such that $\mu(E) \lt \infty$,
there exists a sequence of simple functions $f_n, n = 1, 2,\cdots$ defined on $E$ such that $f(x) = \text{lim}_n f_n(x)$ almost everywhere on $E$.

There are other definitions of measurable functions.
For example $f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal M$ for all open subsets $U\subset B$.
Or $s\circ f$ is measurable whenever $s\in B^*$ where $B^*$ is the dual of $B$ as a topological vector space.

I would like to know the relations if any among various definitions of measurable functions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral this is equivalent to your first definition.  If the Banach space isn't separable, the second definition can have problems.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral as well.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith "*this is equivalent to your first definition.*"
How do you prove this?

Comment: I don't remember how the proof goes.  But I remember reading about it in the book "Sequences and series in Banach spaces,"  by Joseph Diestel.  If I remember the proof in the next day or two, I'll write it here.

Comment: Googling around, it looks like it is called the Pettis measurability theorem.  I couldn't find any online proofs.  Sorry.

Comment: It looks like there is a proof here: http://ocw.tudelft.nl/uploads/media/Lecture01_01.pdf

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith That is very helpful. Thank you so much.